# How to change plotly legendstatus of trace n with a generic button + selectInput through javascript in R shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

Thanks to answers on [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkGPT.png) previous question, I have developed a `plotly` `plot` with `buttons` linked to its `legend`, where clicking the `legend` changes the state of a `reactive variable` containing `T/F` state for each of them, and thus re-renders the `actionbuttons` linked to each `trace` (data group). The other `javascript` does the same in opposite direction, clicking a `button` hides/shows that `trace` + `legend` item in the `plot`.

*Now i'm hoping to add another interaction through a new button + selectinput*

**The question in short:**
How to make clicking a GENERIC button (#0),
change the legend status switch between `TRUE/'legendonly'`
for trace n of plotly plot j (#1),
where `n = input$SelectTrace` (#2)
by using `javascript` + `onclick` argument on that `actionButton`

0 `actionButton` called 'SwitchExt' here
1 It needs to target a specific `plotly plot` since I have multiple
2 a `selectInput` with the traces as choices

**Detailed explanation:**

Now I have the following little problem: 
In my app, in another conditional panel, the user is shown a different set of plots with the same data: 
 - the user can choose which trace to highlight, a button next to it will show whether this trace in the first plot is on/off based on the list of T/F statusses, and then this button will show blue/red, and is linked to the trace selected.

Scenario: 
The user selected group n, 
clicks the new `actionButton 'SwitchExt'`
this triggers `flipYNb_FP1(n)`, 
actionButton `YNbuttons... YNb <- YNElement(n) ....`

```
if(values$dYNbs_cyl_el[[YNb]] == TRUE) {
```

will cause button n to change state.

I can make it also change `values$legenditems[n]`, but in my plot code, `values$legenditems` is wrapped in `isolate({ })` to stop the plot from re-rendering whenever the `javascript` linked to the `legend` changes it.

**Concept of the solution:** 
Basically what I think I need, is rather than changing the `values$legenditems` list directly, is to have another piece of `javascript` that is linked to `actionButton` `'switchExt'` by `'onclick'` and takes `input$SelectTrace` as input, and then changes the `legendstatus` similar to how `javascript js1` does it, but then using `document.getElementById` to grab the value of `input$SelectTrace`, turn it into `numeric`, and update the `legendstatus`.

**The app:**

```
 library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(htmlwidgets)

## js to link buttons to legend
js1 <- c(
  "function toggleLegend(id){",
  "  var ids = id.split('-');",
  "  var plotid = ids[1];",
  "  var plot = document.getElementById(plotid);",
  "  var data = plot.data;",
  "  var v0 = data[index].visible || true;",
  "  var v = v0 == true ? 'legendonly' : true;",
  "  Plotly.restyle(plot, {visible: v}, [index]);",
  "}")

## js code to link legend to buttons
js2 <- c(
  "function(el, x, inputName){",
  "  var id = el.getAttribute('id');",
  "  var d3 = Plotly.d3;",
  "  el.on('plotly_restyle', function(evtData) {",
  "    var out = {};",
  "    d3.select('#' + id + ' g.legend').selectAll('.traces').each(function(){",
  "      var trace = d3.select(this)[0][0].__data__[0].trace;",
  "      out[trace.name] = trace.visible;",
  "    });",
  "    Shiny.setInputValue(inputName, out);",
  "  });",
  "}")



YNElement <-    function(idx){sprintf("YesNo-plot1-%d", idx)}


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(HTML(js1))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(2,
           h5("Keep/Drop choices linked to colorscheme 1"),
           uiOutput('YNbuttons')
    ),
    column(8,
           plotlyOutput("plot1")
    ),
    column(2,
           h5('Switch plot ID and shows the plot remembers the show/hide'),
           actionButton(inputId = 'Switch', label = icon('refresh'), style = "color: #f7ad6e;   background-color: white;  border-color: #f7ad6e;
                        height: 40px; width: 40px; border-radius: 6px;  border-width: 2px; text-align: center;  line-height: 50%; padding: 0px; display:block; margin: 2px"),
           br(),
           h5('New Button that does not work on legend.', style = 'font-weight:bold'),
            uiOutput('newswitch'),
           br(),
           selectInput(inputId = 'SelectTrace', label = 'Select Trace', choices = 1:3, selected = 1)
           ), style = "margin-top:150px"
    )

  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  values <- reactiveValues(Linked_FP1 = T, NrOfTraces = length(unique(mtcars$cyl)))

  observeEvent(input$SwitchExt, { 
    ## trying to make the user be able to switch the buttons linked to the legend on/off through another button that is in another page. 
    flipYNb_FP1(as.numeric(input$SelectTrace)) 
    req(values$legenditems)  ## don't run if legend items does not exist yet. 
    if(values$dYNbs_cyl_el[as.numeric(input$SelectTrace)]) { values$legenditems[[as.numeric(input$SelectTrace)]] <- T } else {   values$legenditems[[as.numeric(input$SelectTrace)]] <- 'legendonly' } ## problem line is here...... since I need to isolate values$legenditems in the plot code
    ## this does not actually cause the legend to change. If I don't isolate, the plot would re-render due to the change in values$legenditems, which is not what we want
  })




  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({

    if(values$Linked_FP1) {colors <- c('red', 'blue', 'black') } else {colors <- c('black', 'orange', 'gray')}
    p1 <- plot_ly()
    p1 <-  add_trace(p1, data = mtcars, x = ~disp, y = ~mpg, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', color = ~as.factor(cyl), colors = colors)
    p1 <- layout(p1, title = 'mtcars group by cyl with switching colors')
    p1 <- plotly_build(p1)

   isolate({ if(values$Linked_FP1) { for(i in seq_along(p1$x$data)){   ## causes the plot to render with previous hide/show selection 
      p1$x$data[[i]]$visible <- values$legenditems[[p1$x$data[[i]]$name]]}  
    } }) ##This block is isolated because otherwise the plot will re-render when the user clicks 1 of the three buttons

    p1 %>% onRender(js2, data = "tracesPlot1")  ## add the javacode to extract the legend status
    })


  observeEvent(input$Switch, { values$Linked_FP1 <- !values$Linked_FP1    })  ## disable the link in my real app, in this dummy app it switches to plot with different id and colors that is not interactive

  observeEvent(values$NrOfTraces, { 
    values$dYNbs_cyl_el <- rep(T,values$NrOfTraces) ## the list of Yes/No status of groups, from which the 3 buttons on the left are build blue or red
    names(values$dYNbs_cyl_el) <- sapply(1:values$NrOfTraces, function(x) {YNElement(x)}) ## add names to that list
    values$legenditems <- rep(T, values$NrOfTraces)  ## make the legenditem list so that the app doesn't crash when user clicks switchExt without first clicking on legend items
    names(values$legenditems) <- sort(unique(mtcars$cyl)) ## add names to that list

  })


    output$newswitch <- renderUI({ 
    req(input$SelectTrace)
      print(input$SelectTrace)
      if(values$dYNbs_cyl_el[as.numeric(input$SelectTrace)]) { 
    actionButton(inputId = 'SwitchExt', label = icon('refresh'), style = "color: #339fff;   background-color: white;  border-color: #339fff;
                        height: 40px; width: 40px; border-radius: 6px;  border-width: 2px; text-align: center;  line-height: 50%; padding: 0px; display:block; margin: 2px", 
                 onclick = "toggleLegend(this.id);"
                 )}
    else { actionButton(inputId = 'SwitchExt', label = icon('refresh'), style = "color: #f7ad6e;   background-color: white;  border-color: #f7ad6e;
                        height: 40px; width: 40px; border-radius: 6px;  border-width: 2px; text-align: center;  line-height: 50%; padding: 0px; display:block; margin: 2px", 
                   onclick = "toggleLegend(this.id);"
                   )}
    })


  observeEvent(input$tracesPlot1, {
    if(values$Linked_FP1) {
    listTraces <- input$tracesPlot1
    values$legenditems <- listTraces  ## store the list of show/hide for when the plot re-renders here
    listTracesTF <- gsub('legendonly', FALSE, listTraces)
    listTracesTF <- as.logical(listTracesTF)
    lapply(1:values$NrOfTraces, function(el) {
      if(el <= length(listTracesTF)) {
        YNb <- YNElement(el)
        if(values$dYNbs_cyl_el[[YNb]] != listTracesTF[el]) {
          values$dYNbs_cyl_el[[YNb]] <- listTracesTF[el]
        }
      }
    })
    }
  })

  output$YNbuttons <- renderUI({
    req(values$NrOfTraces)
    lapply(1:values$NrOfTraces, function(el) {
      YNb <- YNElement(el)
      if(values$Linked_FP1) {
        if(values$dYNbs_cyl_el[[YNb]] == TRUE) {
        div(actionButton(inputId = YNb, label = icon("check"), 
                         style = "color: #339FFF;   background-color: white;  border-color: #339FFF;height: 34px; width: 34px; border-radius: 6px;  border-width: 2px; text-align: center;  line-height: 50%; padding: 0px; display:block; margin: 2px", 
                         onclick = "toggleLegend(this.id);"))
      } else {
        div(actionButton(inputId = YNb, label = icon("times"), 
                         style = "color: #ff4d4d;   background-color: white;  border-color: #ff4d4d;height: 34px; width: 34px; border-radius: 6px;  border-width: 2px; text-align: center;  line-height: 50%; padding: 0px; display:block; margin: 2px", 
                         onclick = "toggleLegend(this.id);"))
      }
      } 
    })
  }) 


  flipYNb_FP1 <- function(idx){
    YNb <- YNElement(idx)
    values$dYNbs_cyl_el[[YNb]] <- !values$dYNbs_cyl_el[[YNb]]
  }

  observe({
    lapply(1:values$NrOfTraces, function(ob) {
      YNElement <- YNElement(ob)
      observeEvent(input[[YNElement]], {
        if(!values$Linked_FP1) { flipYNb_FP1(ob) }
        }, ignoreInit = T)
    })
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**solution:**
After some struggle with some unintended behavior I figured out that I needed to remove the observer for switchExt-plot1 to stop buttons from flipping twice.

```
observeEvent(input[['SwitchExt-plot1']], { 
         flipYNb_FP1(as.numeric(input$SelectTrace)) 
      })
```

**The working app is this:**

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(htmlwidgets)

## js to link buttons to legend
js1 <- c(
  "function toggleLegend(id){",
  "  var ids = id.split('-');",
  "  var plotid = ids[1];",
  "  var index = parseInt(ids[2])-1;", ## correct as the YN buttons are named YesNo-plot1-%d
  "  var plot = document.getElementById(plotid);",
  "  var data = plot.data;",
  "  var v0 = data[index].visible || true;",
  "  var v = v0 == true ? 'legendonly' : true;",
  "  Plotly.restyle(plot, {visible: v}, [index]);",
  "}",
  "function toggleLegend2(id){",
  "  var index = parseInt($('#SelectTrace').val())-1;",
  "  var ids = id.split('-');",
  "  var plotid = ids[1];",
  "  var plot = document.getElementById(plotid);",
  "  var data = plot.data;",
  "  var v0 = data[index].visible || true;",
  "  var v = v0 == true ? 'legendonly' : true;",
  "  Plotly.restyle(plot, {visible: v}, [index]);",
  "}")

## js code to link legend to buttons
js2 <- c(
  "function(el, x, inputName){",
  "  var id = el.getAttribute('id');",
  "  var d3 = Plotly.d3;",
  "  el.on('plotly_restyle', function(evtData) {",
  "    var out = {};",
  "    d3.select('#' + id + ' g.legend').selectAll('.traces').each(function(){",
  "      var trace = d3.select(this)[0][0].__data__[0].trace;",
  "      out[trace.name] = trace.visible;",
  "    });",
  "    Shiny.setInputValue(inputName, out);",
  "  });",
  "}")



YNElement <-    function(idx){sprintf("YesNo-plot1-%d", idx)}


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(HTML(js1))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(2,
           h5("Keep/Drop choices linked to colorscheme 1"),
           uiOutput('YNbuttons')
    ),
    column(8,
           plotlyOutput("plot1")
    ),
    column(2,
           h5('New Button that does not work on legend.', style = 'font-weight:bold'),
           uiOutput('newswitch'),
           br(),
           selectInput(inputId = 'SelectTrace', label = 'Select Trace', choices = 1:3, selected = 1)
           ), style = "margin-top:150px"
  )

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  values <- reactiveValues(Linked_FP1 = T, NrOfTraces = length(unique(mtcars$cyl)))

output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    if(values$Linked_FP1) {colors <- c('red', 'blue', 'black') } else {colors <- c('black', 'orange', 'gray')}
    p1 <- plot_ly()
    p1 <-  add_trace(p1, data = mtcars, x = ~disp, y = ~mpg, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', color = ~as.factor(cyl), colors = colors)
    p1 <- layout(p1, title = 'mtcars group by cyl with switching colors')
    p1 <- plotly_build(p1)

    isolate({ if(values$Linked_FP1) { for(i in seq_along(p1$x$data)){   ## causes the plot to render with previous hide/show selection 
      p1$x$data[[i]]$visible <- values$legenditems[[p1$x$data[[i]]$name]]}  
    } }) ##This block is isolated because otherwise the plot will re-render when the user clicks 1 of the three buttons

    p1 %>% onRender(js2, data = "tracesPlot1")  ## add the javacode to extract the legend status
  })


  observeEvent(values$NrOfTraces, { 
    values$dYNbs_cyl_el <- rep(T,values$NrOfTraces) ## the list of Yes/No status of groups, from which the 3 buttons on the left are build blue or red
    names(values$dYNbs_cyl_el) <- sapply(1:values$NrOfTraces, function(x) {YNElement(x)}) ## add names to that list
    values$legenditems <- rep(T, values$NrOfTraces)  ## make the legenditem list so that the app doesn't crash when user clicks switchExt without first clicking on legend items
    names(values$legenditems) <- sort(unique(mtcars$cyl)) ## add names to that list

  })


  output$newswitch <- renderUI({ 
    req(input$SelectTrace)
    if(values$dYNbs_cyl_el[as.numeric(input$SelectTrace)]) { 
      actionButton(inputId = 'SwitchExt-plot1', label = icon('refresh'), style = "color: #339fff;   background-color: white;  border-color: #339fff;
                   height: 40px; width: 40px; border-radius: 6px;  border-width: 2px; text-align: center;  line-height: 50%; padding: 0px; display:block; margin: 2px", 
                   onclick = "toggleLegend2(this.id)")
    }
    else { actionButton(inputId = 'SwitchExt-plot1', label = icon('refresh'), style = "color: #f7ad6e;   background-color: white;  border-color: #f7ad6e;
                        height: 40px; width: 40px; border-radius: 6px;  border-width: 2px; text-align: center;  line-height: 50%; padding: 0px; display:block; margin: 2px", 
                        onclick = "toggleLegend2(this.id)")}
  })


  observeEvent(input$tracesPlot1, {
    if(values$Linked_FP1) {
      listTraces <- input$tracesPlot1
      values$legenditems <- listTraces  ## store the list of show/hide for when the plot re-renders here
      listTracesTF <- gsub('legendonly', FALSE, listTraces)
      listTracesTF <- as.logical(listTracesTF)
      lapply(1:values$NrOfTraces, function(el) {
        if(el <= length(listTracesTF)) {
          YNb <- YNElement(el)
          if(values$dYNbs_cyl_el[[YNb]] != listTracesTF[el]) {
            values$dYNbs_cyl_el[[YNb]] <- listTracesTF[el]
          }
        }
      })
    }
  })

  output$YNbuttons <- renderUI({
    req(values$NrOfTraces)
    lapply(1:values$NrOfTraces, function(el) {
      YNb <- YNElement(el)
      if(values$Linked_FP1) {
        if(values$dYNbs_cyl_el[[YNb]] == TRUE) {
          div(actionButton(inputId = YNb, label = icon("check"), 
                           style = "color: #339FFF;   background-color: white;  border-color: #339FFF;height: 34px; width: 34px; border-radius: 6px;  border-width: 2px; text-align: center;  line-height: 50%; padding: 0px; display:block; margin: 2px", 
                           onclick = "toggleLegend(this.id);"))
        } else {
          div(actionButton(inputId = YNb, label = icon("times"), 
                           style = "color: #ff4d4d;   background-color: white;  border-color: #ff4d4d;height: 34px; width: 34px; border-radius: 6px;  border-width: 2px; text-align: center;  line-height: 50%; padding: 0px; display:block; margin: 2px", 
                           onclick = "toggleLegend(this.id);"))
        }
      } 
    })
  }) 


  flipYNb_FP1 <- function(idx){
    YNb <- YNElement(idx)
    values$dYNbs_cyl_el[[YNb]] <- !values$dYNbs_cyl_el[[YNb]]
  }

  observe({
    lapply(1:values$NrOfTraces, function(ob) {
      YNElement <- YNElement(ob)
      observeEvent(input[[YNElement]], {
        if(!values$Linked_FP1) { flipYNb_FP1(ob) }
      }, ignoreInit = T)
    })
  })

    }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

image to support comment: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand, but let's start with something.

```
js1 <- c(
  "function toggleLegend(id){",
  "  var ids = id.split('-');",
  "  var plotid = ids[1];",
  "  var index = parseInt(ids[2])-1;",
  "  var plot = document.getElementById(plotid);",
  "  var data = plot.data;",
  "  var v0 = data[index].visible || true;",
  "  var v = v0 == true ? 'legendonly' : true;",
  "  Plotly.restyle(plot, {visible: v}, [index]);",
  "}",
  "function toggleLegend2(){",
  "  var index = parseInt($('#SelectTrace').val())-1;",
  "  var plot = document.getElementById('plot1');",
  "  var data = plot.data;",
  "  var v0 = data[index].visible || true;",
  "  var v = v0 == true ? 'legendonly' : true;",
  "  Plotly.restyle(plot, {visible: v}, [index]);",
  "}")

actionButton(inputId = 'SwitchExt', ......, onclick = "toggleLegend2()")
```

Is it what you want ?

Comment: hmmm i'm confused, I get the jist of the answer, but it doesn't seem to do anything. I will update the adjusted app into the question

Comment: @Mark You have forgotten to change the `onclick` attribute of the button: `onclick = "toggleLegend2();"`.

Comment: Ah I must have missed that somehow. Got that working indeed. Now I tried to step it up by making it plot specific: including plot name in the switch button (now 'swtichExt-plot1' and altering the javascript to use 'id' like in the togglelegend() function, but then it stopped working again

Comment: @Mark You don't have to do `var index = parseInt(ids[2])-1;`. The index is given by `SelectTrace` (there are two `var index` in your code). Moreover there's nothing in `ids[2]`. When you split `SwitchExt-plot1` according to `-`, you get the array `['SwitchExt','plot1']`, it has only two elements, indexed by `0` and `1`.

Comment: @Mark I still see `var index = parseInt(ids[2])-1;` in your code. If you remove this line, the second button works as expected. You attach `onclick = "toggleLegend2()"` to the first button (`Switch`), which makes no sense.  What this button is supposed to do ?

Comment: going crazy here... was a copy paste error. Updated it again, toggleLegend() does need the parseInt(ids[2])-1 though. Remove the 'Switch' button as it's irrelevant. Still get  ON-OFF OFF-ON behaviour instead of ON-ON vs OFF-OFF for button - legend combi though

Comment: @Mark I don't understand what you mean. `toggleLegend2` toggles the legend of the selected trace. So what's the problem ? What do you mean by ON-OFF, etc ?

Comment: I mean that when I run the current updated app in the question, and click on switch, the legend of trace n goes to 'legendonly', but button n stays blue. Click it again, trace n goes to TRUE, button goes to red.... while they should go TRUE + blue, legendonly+red

Comment: Problem solved. It was due to the observer on switchExt-plot1 causing double flipping. I'm quite happy that I also managed to add this modification myself to make it plot + matching switchbutton specific: "  var index = parseInt($('#SelectTrace' + plotid).val())-1;",

Comment: Believe it or not, I just spend 12 hours trying to work this into my main app. For some reason it would not work, no matter what I tried. Finally found the solution though. It seems the javascript fails when selectInput(inputId = 'SelectTrace' is build in the server through renderUI..... Eventhough the javascript is not hanging on this dropdown, it is listening to it, and apparently that gave the problem.