# R Shiny plotly update trace colors with javascript when colourInput is build in the server

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

This is a modified version to the previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55076025/r-shiny-plotly-change-color-of-a-trace-with-javascript-without-affecting-mar/55082545#55082545)

In this app (which reflects my real app better) the following situation happens:

I have 2 sets of plots,
- the 2 plots of a set show the same traces, just different columns plotted
- each plot is on a different page in my app
- The two plots should be linked to 1 set of `colourInputs`, on page 2
- The `colourInputs` are built in the server with `renderUI` *1

*1:  for this reason, I believe that `p %>% onRender(js)`  approach will not work as I saw earlier in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55068763/how-to-change-plotly-legendstatus-of-trace-n-with-a-generic-button-selectinput/55078239#55078239) question for the `YNbuttons` there

**Goal:** 
if `colourInput` `'COL_button_plot1_plot2_N'` changes -> change the `color` of `trace` `N-1` (*2)  in `plot1` AND `plot2`

*2: trace numbers run for `0-n,` thus `colourinput nr -1`

I altered the naming code for the colorInputs to contain the names of both plots they should target:

```
COLElement_1 <-    function(idx){sprintf("COL_button_plot1_plot2_%d",idx)}
```

I suspect that we need `onclick = "toggleColor(this.id)")` attached on the `colourInput` rather than `onRender()` on the `plot` due to the `renderUI()` `uiOutput()` of the `colourInputs`

So far I designed an attempt at a javascript that grabs the 2 plot IDs and data and has the restyle function in it, but I'm stuck on how to get it to work as intended in the app. It might at least help to get the idea across.

```
jscolor <- c(
  "function toggleColor(id){",
  "  var color = this.value;", # get the color of the colourpicker
  "  var ids = id.split('_');", # split the ids
  "  var plotAid = ids[2];", #get the id of plotA (plot1 or 3)
  "  var plotBid = ids[3];", #get the id of plotB (plot2 or 4)
  "  var index = parseInt(ids[4]) -1;", #get the trace number to target
  "  var plotA = document.getElementById(plot1id);", #get the plot element
  "  var dataA = plotA.data;", #access the plot data
  "  var markerA = dataA[index].marker;", #access the plot's markers
  "  markerA.color = color;",  # set the marker color
  "  Plotly.restyle(plotA, {marker: markerA}, [index]);", #restyle plotA
  "  var plotB = document.getElementById(plotBid);", # repeat steps for plot2
  "  var dataB = plotB.data;",
  "  var markerB = dataB[index].marker;",
  "  markerB.color = color;",
  "  Plotly.restyle(plotB, {marker: markerB}, [index]);",
  "  });"
)
```

THE TEST APP:

```
   library(plotly)
    library(shiny)
    library(colourpicker)
    library(htmlwidgets)

# jscolor <- c(......)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(HTML(jscolor))  ## to add the javascript to the app
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(4,plotlyOutput("plot1")),
    column(4,plotlyOutput("plot2")),
    column(4,uiOutput('buttons_color_1')
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(4,plotlyOutput("plot3")),
    column(4,plotlyOutput("plot4")),
    column(4,uiOutput('buttons_color_2'))
)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   #functions to make colorinput IDs
  COLElement_1 <-    function(idx){sprintf("COL_button_plot1_plot2_%d",idx)}
  COLElement_2 <-    function(idx){sprintf("COL_button_plot3_plot4_%d",idx)}

  TheColors <- c('#383838', '#5b195b','#1A237E', '#000080', '#224D17', '#cccc00', '#b37400',  '#990000', 
                 '#505050',  '#a02ca0',  '#000099', '#2645e0', '#099441', '#e5e500', '#cc8400', '#cc0000', 
                 '#737373', '#e53fe5', '#0000FF', '#4479e1',  '#60A830', '#ffff00','#e69500', '#ff0000', 
                 '#b2b2b2', '#eb6ceb', '#6666ff', '#d0a3ff', '#9FDA40',  '#ffff7f', '#ffa500', '#ff4c4c',
                 '#d9d9d9',  '#f198f1',  '#C5CAE9','#BBDEFB','#D9DF1D', '#ffffcc','#ffc04d', '#ff9999')

  values <- reactiveValues(colors1 = TheColors, colors2 = sort(TheColors))
  lapply(c(1:2), function(i) {
    output[[paste('buttons_color_', i,sep = '')]] <- renderUI({
      isolate({ lapply(1:3, function(x) {  ## 3 in my app changes based on clustering output of my model
        Idname <- if(i == 1) { COLElement_1(x) } else {COLElement_2(x) }
        div(colourpicker::colourInput(inputId = Idname, label = NULL,
                                      palette = "limited", allowedCols = TheColors,
                                      value = values[[paste('colors', i, sep = '')]][x],
                                      showColour = "background", returnName = TRUE),
            style = " height: 30px; width: 30px; border-radius: 6px;  border-width: 2px; text-align:center; padding: 0px; display:block; margin: 10px",
            onclick = "toggleColor(this.id)")
      })
      })})

    outputOptions(output, paste('buttons_color_', i,sep = ''), suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)
  })



  myplotly <- function(THEPLOT, xvar, setnr) {
    markersize <- input[[paste('markersize', THEPLOT, sep = '_')]]
    markerlegendsize <- input[[paste('legendsize', THEPLOT, sep = '_')]]
    colors <- isolate ({values[[paste('colors', setnr, sep = '')]]  })
    p <- plot_ly(source = paste('plotlyplot', THEPLOT, sep = '.'))
    p <-  add_trace(p, data = mtcars, x = mtcars[[xvar]], y = ~mpg, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', color = ~as.factor(cyl), colors = colors)
    p <- layout(p, title = 'mtcars group by cyl with switching colors')
    p <- plotly_build(p)
    p 
  }

  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({ myplotly('plot1', 'hp', 1) })
  output$plot2 <- renderPlotly({ myplotly('plot2', 'disp', 1)})
  output$plot3 <- renderPlotly({ myplotly('plot3','hp', 2)})
  output$plot4 <- renderPlotly({ myplotly('plot4', 'disp', 2)})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**UPDATED APP:**
Got the working solution thanks to the answer, but when I start changing the plot names it breaks. Here I changed all references of 'plot1' to plotx.

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(colourpicker)
library(htmlwidgets)

jscolor <- c(
  "function toggleColor(id){",
  "  var color = document.getElementById(id).value;", # get the color of the colourpicker
  "  var ids = id.split('_');", # split the ids
  "  var plotAid = ids[2];", #get the id of plotA (plotx or 3)
  "  var plotBid = ids[3];", #get the id of plotB (plot2 or 4)
  "  var index = parseInt(ids[4]) -1;", #get the trace number to target
  "  var plotA = document.getElementById(plotAid);", #get the plot element
  "  var dataA = plotA.data;", #access the plot data
  "  var markerA = dataA[index].marker;", #access the plot's markers
  "  markerA.color = color;",  # set the marker color
  "  Plotly.restyle(plotA, {marker: markerA}, [index]);", #restyle plotA
  "  var plotB = document.getElementById(plotBid);", # repeat steps for plot2
  "  var dataB = plotB.data;",
  "  var markerB = dataB[index].marker;",
  "  markerB.color = color;",
  "  Plotly.restyle(plotB, {marker: markerB}, [index]);",
  "};"
)

colourInput2 <- function(inputId, label, value = "white", 
                         showColour = c("both", "text", "background"), 
                         palette = c("square", "limited"), allowedCols = NULL,
                         allowTransparent = FALSE, returnName = FALSE, 
                         onchange){
  input <- colourInput(inputId, label, value, showColour, palette, 
                       allowedCols, allowTransparent, returnName)
  attribs <- c(input$children[[2]]$attribs, onchange = onchange)
  input$children[[2]]$attribs <- attribs
  input
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(HTML(jscolor))  ## to add the javascript to the app
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(4,plotlyOutput("plotx")),
    column(4,plotlyOutput("plot2")),
    column(4,uiOutput('buttons_color_1')
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(4,plotlyOutput("plot3")),
    column(4,plotlyOutput("plot4")),
    column(4,uiOutput('buttons_color_2'))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #functions to make colorinput IDs
  COLElement_1 <-    function(idx){sprintf("COL_button_plotx_plot2_%d",idx)}
  COLElement_2 <-    function(idx){sprintf("COL_button_plot3_plot4_%d",idx)}

  TheColors <- c('#383838', '#5b195b','#1A237E', '#000080', '#224D17', '#cccc00', '#b37400',  '#990000', 
                 '#505050',  '#a02ca0',  '#000099', '#2645e0', '#099441', '#e5e500', '#cc8400', '#cc0000', 
                 '#737373', '#e53fe5', '#0000FF', '#4479e1',  '#60A830', '#ffff00','#e69500', '#ff0000', 
                 '#b2b2b2', '#eb6ceb', '#6666ff', '#d0a3ff', '#9FDA40',  '#ffff7f', '#ffa500', '#ff4c4c',
                 '#d9d9d9',  '#f198f1',  '#C5CAE9','#BBDEFB','#D9DF1D', '#ffffcc','#ffc04d', '#ff9999')

  values <- reactiveValues(colors1 = TheColors, colors2 = sort(TheColors))
  lapply(c(1:2), function(i) {
    output[[paste('buttons_color_', i,sep = '')]] <- renderUI({
      inputs <- lapply(1:3, function(x) {  ## 3 in my app changes based on clustering output of my model
        Idname <- if(i == 1) { COLElement_1(x) } else {COLElement_2(x) }
        colour_input <- colourInput2(inputId = Idname, label = NULL,
                                     palette = "limited", allowedCols = TheColors,
                                     value = isolate(values[[paste('colors', i, sep = '')]][x]),
                                     showColour = "background", returnName = FALSE, 
                                     onchange = "toggleColor(this.id)")
        div(colour_input,
            style = "height: 30px; width: 30px; border-radius: 6px;  border-width: 2px; text-align:center; padding: 0px; display:block; margin: 10px"
        )
      })
      do.call(tagList, inputs)
    })
    # useless: outputOptions(output, paste('buttons_color_', i,sep = ''), suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)
  })


  myplotly <- function(THEPLOT, xvar, setnr) {
    markersize <- 2
    markerlegendsize <- 10
    colors <- isolate ({values[[paste('colors', setnr, sep = '')]]  })
    p <- plot_ly(source = paste('plotlyplot', THEPLOT, sep = '.'))
    p <-  add_trace(p, data = mtcars, x = mtcars[[xvar]], y = ~mpg, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', color = ~as.factor(cyl), colors = colors)
    p <- layout(p, title = 'mtcars group by cyl with switching colors')
    p <- plotly_build(p)
    p 
  }

  output$plotx <- renderPlotly({ myplotly('plotx', 'hp', 1) })
  output$plot2 <- renderPlotly({ myplotly('plot2', 'disp', 1)})
  output$plot3 <- renderPlotly({ myplotly('plot3','hp', 2)})
  output$plot4 <- renderPlotly({ myplotly('plot4', 'disp', 2)})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some typos in your JS code, and `this.value` does not return the value of the colour picker.

```
jscolor <- c(
  "function toggleColor(id){",
  "  var color = document.getElementById(id).value;", # get the color of the colourpicker
  "  var ids = id.split('_');", # split the ids
  "  var plotAid = ids[2];", #get the id of plotA (plot1 or 3)
  "  var plotBid = ids[3];", #get the id of plotB (plot2 or 4)
  "  var index = parseInt(ids[4]) -1;", #get the trace number to target
  "  var plotA = document.getElementById(plotAid);", #get the plot element
  "  var dataA = plotA.data;", #access the plot data
  "  var markerA = dataA[index].marker;", #access the plot's markers
  "  markerA.color = color;",  # set the marker color
  "  Plotly.restyle(plotA, {marker: markerA}, [index]);", #restyle plotA
  "  var plotB = document.getElementById(plotBid);", # repeat steps for plot2
  "  var dataB = plotB.data;",
  "  var markerB = dataB[index].marker;",
  "  markerB.color = color;",
  "  Plotly.restyle(plotB, {marker: markerB}, [index]);",
  "};"
)
```

Now let's modify `colourInput`, allowing a `onchange` attribute:

```
colourInput2 <- function(inputId, label, value = "white", 
                         showColour = c("both", "text", "background"), 
                         palette = c("square", "limited"), allowedCols = NULL,
                         allowTransparent = FALSE, returnName = FALSE, 
                         onchange){
  input <- colourInput(inputId, label, value, showColour, palette, 
                       allowedCols, allowTransparent, returnName)
  attribs <- c(input$children[[2]]$attribs, onchange = onchange)
  input$children[[2]]$attribs <- attribs
  input
}
```

In `server.R`:

```
  lapply(c(1:2), function(i) {
    output[[paste('buttons_color_', i,sep = '')]] <- renderUI({
      inputs <- lapply(1:3, function(x) {  ## 3 in my app changes based on clustering output of my model
        Idname <- if(i == 1) { COLElement_1(x) } else {COLElement_2(x) }
        colour_input <- colourInput2(inputId = Idname, label = NULL,
                                     palette = "limited", allowedCols = TheColors,
                                     value = isolate(values[[paste('colors', i, sep = '')]][x]),
                                     showColour = "background", returnName = FALSE, 
                                     onchange = "toggleColor(this.id)")
        div(colour_input,
            style = "height: 30px; width: 30px; border-radius: 6px;  border-width: 2px; text-align:center; padding: 0px; display:block; margin: 10px"
        )
      })
      do.call(tagList, inputs)
    })
    # useless: outputOptions(output, paste('buttons_color_', i,sep = ''), suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)
  })
```

Comment: I'm actually surprised how close I was to a correct javascript. Seems I'm at least learning things from all your help Stephane!

Comment: Gettig some strange problems when I combine this solution with the button legend link javascript. Will continue tomorrow to see if I can figure out what goes wrong

Comment: trying to figure out what goes wrong by modifying the working solution step by step towards my real app. I found out that the first obstacle seems to be the plot names. In the updated app I replaced the name of one of the plots from plot1 to plotx and suddenly the plot doesn't work anymore eventhough all references of its name have been changed. Can you figure out what I'm missing Stephane?

Comment: Stépahne, do you have any clue why it doesn't work with different plot names?  I'm stuck

Comment: @Mark No idea sorry. That's very weird. There's no reason that doesn't work with a different name.

Comment: but you're getting the same behavior? Very strange then indeed. Not sure what to do about it then.. Not looking forward to rename all my plots in my main App

Comment: @Mark I've tried to replace `plotx` with `plotW` and that works! Very weird.

Comment: I did some more playing around, it almost seems that plot3 and plot4 are more prone to the bug than plot1 and plot2, but maybe that is just my imagination. I posted an SO question specifically about the name issue, perhaps one day someone will figure out why. I also replaced the underscores in the names to see if that mattered, but not really. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55149416/mysterious-javascript-bug-that-is-depending-on-what-plot-object-names-are-used-i

Comment: somebody made a comment on the other question and then removed it that it was due to the colourInput2 function. He didn't elaborate before deleting the comment though...